# Android image intent not displaying image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

so I have been trying to learn Android Studio for the past month and I just started learning Firebase so I was planning on developing a little side-project to upload pictures to Cloud Storage after getting them from a user's device.

**Problem:**
So I have been trying to display the image taken from gallery,but it is not displaying the image.It asks the user for a picture but doesn't display it

**Code:**

**HomeFragment.java:**

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.clickPhoto:
                break; 
            case R.id.addPhoto:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click Event tak hua", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.savePhotoButton:
                downloadPhoto();
                break;
            case R.id.shareButton:
                // stuff
                break;
        }
    }
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Idhar tak aaye kya?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Display collected image.
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            photo.setImageURI(uri);
            // Get roast from Firestore
            CollectionReference colRef = db.collection("roasts");
            colRef.whereEqualTo("a", true)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Foreach loop se pehle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                    String roast = documentSnapshot.getString("a");
                                    roastText.setText(roast);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="119dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.669" />
```

Comment: photo.setImageUri(uri);

Comment: that is not working

Comment: There is no reason that it should not work.

Comment: I have debugged the code and found out that the code does not pass the if statement inside OnActivityResult

Comment: Which if statement? You have two.

Comment: both of them don't

Comment: You posted four switch cases. Why so much code? The addPhoto PICK_IMAGE case was enough. The same in onActivityResult. Only the if for PICK_IMAGE should have done it. Please update your post with minimal code only.

Comment: I have removed the first IF statement and the switch case in the onClick method., should it work now?

Comment: You did not change anything here. Edit your post please. Show what you have now. `photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` You have that only once.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: You still have four cases and a switch. Mininmal code please! And why did you post code after the line photo.setImageURI(uri); ? That code is not relevant for your problem i suppose.

Comment: They are quite relevant but I don't get it, how is minimal code going to help out in this situation, I feel the parameters in the IF statement are wrong, so it would be nice if you would elaborate on that

Comment: PLEASE POST MINIMAL CODE.